# Show primeNG toast from generic class

Tags: primeng

I have this code in component.ts class

```
    constructor(private inventoryService: InventoryService, 
                private listService: ListService,
                private messageService: MessageService,
                private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) 
            {
                this.util = new Util(this.messageService);
            }
```

and in the Util.ts class this code:

```
    import {MessageService} from 'primeng/api';
    
    export class Util
    {
        constructor(private messageService: MessageService) 
        {
            this.messageService = new MessageService();
        }
        
        ShowMessage(buinessOk:boolean,serverOk:boolean,message:string)
        {
            console.log("empieza el durante");
            var severity="error";
            if(buinessOk && serverOk)
            {
                severity = "success"
            }
            
            this.messageService.add({severity:severity, summary:"", detail:message, life:3000});
     
     
        }
    }
```

But the message in the p-stoast never is Shown. That code in from ChatGPT which drives me crazy beacuase it doesn't work.

```
ShowMessage(buinessOk:boolean,serverOk:boolean,message:string)
    {
        console.log("empieza el durante");
        var severity="error";
        if(buinessOk && serverOk)
        {
            severity = "success"
        }
        
        this.messageService.add({severity:severity, summary:"", detail:message, life:3000});
 
 
    }
```

i put this piece of code in the component class and It Works.

Comment: I don`t know why Stackoverflow doesn`t show the code formatted

Comment: I placed `<p-toast key='app'></p-toast>` in my app-component.html file, then in the class constructor, `constructor( ..., private _messageService: MessageService ) { }` and finally call the service with the 'app' key as follows: `this._messageService.add({key: 'app', sticky: true, severity:'info', summary:'Toast Message', detail:'Via MessageService'});`

Answer (score 0):

This line should be removed from the `Util`'s constructor:

```js
this.messageService = new MessageService();
```

You're overriding the correct `MessageService` instance with the one you created manually. Of course that's not going to produce any visible result.

Comment: I`ve removed it, but the result is the same.

Comment: Are you calling the `Util.ShowMessage` method? [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-scrollpanel-demo-yyzrjb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn`t Calling Util.ShowMessage, Now It Worked,